# How to bypass the organization proxy for a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application. I am using a third party API class for my service response. In my controller I have created a `GET` method with query parameter and inside the method I am calling the service class. Inside the service class I am using the third party API (to get the response).
The problem here the third party API has one authentication API key to use there API call. And when I am running the spring boot application and calling my API while connected to the VPN then it's throwing `APIException:SocketTimeout`. But when I disconnect the VPN the response comes as expected. Could anybody please suggest me how to overcome this issue. Or how should I bypass my network proxy.

Thank You

Comment: "*Or how should I bypass my network proxy.*" - If you find a way to bypass the proxy, you should immediately report it to the network administrators since it could be a security vulnerability. In short: the proxy should not be bypassable unless special access is granted through the administration team. That said, are you sure that the behaviour as-is is expected from within the VPN? If yes: talk to your network adminstrators, explain your situation and ask for a solution.

Comment: Yes we are okay to bypass this network proxy. That's granted.

Answer (score 0):

so this means that you have a network issue. Either the domain that you're accessing block your vpn region or from your vpn there is some limitations. Could you please make a curl, and see where you're request got blocked ? If doesn't pass your vpn connection, please discuss with your network admin to add it to some sort of whitelisting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes curl I did. And in curl command I am trying to pass the third party API call (endpoint url) with my API key for authorization and it works fine. But with my endpoint it's failing because I am using there API instance in my application. Please suggest if you have any idea on it.